# Converting XML to Object back to XML without knowing class

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm parsing unknown XML strings that could be anything.

I tried the following code

```
            String XMLString = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><dataset><height>true</height></dataset>";


            Object xmlObj = JAXB.unmarshal(new StringReader(XMLString), Object.class);

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            JAXB.marshal(xmlObj, sw);
            String xmlString = sw.toString();

            System.out.println(xmlString);
```

this however prints out

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<elementNSImpl>
    <textContent>true</textContent>
</elementNSImpl>
```

How can I maintain the original node names?

Comment: What is your end goal? what do you want to do with the XML that you read? (If you just wanted to print it - no need to parse it)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you've "unmarshalled" a DOM element.

To unmarshal something with JAXB you need to create a `JAXBContext` for a certain set of classes. You can enumerate them directly or using a context path (one or more package names), but you have to provide this. Otherwise JAXB won't know what to unmarshal.

If you're completely generic about what you unmarshal, then JAXB may be a bad choice. You can parse DOM instead. JAXB is about mapping XML to instances of Java classes. For this to work you have to let JAXB know which classes to consider.